# How to pick data in html page header from the current url

Tags: html

How to pick data in  html page header from the current url.

My URL is coming as

file:///D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Desktop/HTML/Basic2.html?course_id=CO2

I want to write the Heading as :

**Add Prefrence for training for "course_id"**

In the above course_id should be CO2.

```
<title>Employee Prefrence for Traning</title>
    <h1>Add Prefrence</h1>
    <hr>
```

I am getting the values in the URL by using get value function.

Comment: from where the URL is getting?

Comment: are you making the URL something like this `basic2.html?course_id=".$objResult["course_id"]."`?  Or how are you creating the URL?

Answer (score 1):

With javascript you can get the current path, like:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

from this you can find the index of the course_id, with:

```
var index =pathname.indexOf("course_id");
```

or

```
var index=pathname.indexOf("=");
```

and at last you want the course id, you can get this by using a substring:

```
var courseID = pathname.substr(index).
```

Hope this will help you out.